# How can I get term id or term name on user profile page

Tags: users, taxonomy-terms

I have a vocabulary(lessons) with terms as math,art,chemistry etc..

These terms are on user page in my lesson field.
For example:
My Lessons: Math,Geography,Art

Scenario: I'm gonna use linked field with different destination. When I click math term on user page It will goes to view page with path ../teacher/math to list all related teachers.
Views page is ok no problem. 
But I can't get term name or id on user page. No available tokens.
Terms new linked destionation as  teacher/[my_lessons:term:name]

I've tried

- teacher/[my_lessons:term:name]
- teacher/[my_lessons:term:tid]
- teacher/[my_lessons:name]
- teacher/[current-page:user:field-my-lessons:tid]
- teacher/[current-page:user:field-my-lessons:name]

None of them work.

teacher/[current-page:user:field-my-lessons] gets all term name.

How can I get users lessons term name or id ?

Comment: _teacher/[current-page:user:field-my-lessons] gets all term name._ assuming there are multiple entries for that field that makes sense - what would you expect to happen instead? How would the system know which term you want it to show?

Comment: For example: Math id :185 . It should get math id then it should go url(domain.com/ theacher/185) when I click math on user profile page.. Or it should go domain.com/teacher/math to list teachers if I use term name on views contextual filter ..ID or name doens't matter. It's ok which one of them works. This scenario works on node types with any taxonomy... Because I can get term name with [node:field-my-lessons:name] . But I can't get individual term name or id on user pages.

Comment: You can create view block of users in which display a field "lessons" with contexual filter "User: User ID"(Provide default value:user id from logged in user),Rewrite(Output this field as a custom link) your lession Field with teacher/{{ field_your_field__target_id }},then place the block on /user/* ,i think its a simple way to do the same